# R - reading several data tables from one text file

Tags: r, parsing

I am new to R and trying to learn how to read the text below. I am using

`data <- read.table("myvertices.txt", stringsAsFactors=TRUE, sep=",")`

hoping to convey that the "FID..." should be associated with the comma separated numbers below them.
The error I get is:

> Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
>     line 13 did not have 2 elements

How would I read the following format

```
FID001:
-120.9633,51.8496
-121.42749,52.293
-121.25453,52.3195
FID002:
-65.4794,47.69011
-65.4797,47.0401
FID003:
-65.849,47.5215
-65.467,47.515
```

into something like

```
FID001 -120.9633  51.8496
FID001 -121.42749 52.293
FID001 -121.25453 52.3195
FID002 -65.4794   47.69011
FID002 -65.4797   47.0401
FID003 -65.849    47.5215
FID003 -65.467    47.515
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible way to achieve this:

```
data <- read.table("myvertices.txt")            # Read as-is.
fid1 <- c(grep("^FID", data$V1), nrow(data) +1) # Get the row numbers containing "FID.."
df1 <- diff(x = fid1, lag = 1)                  # Calculate the length+1 rows to read
listdata <- lapply(seq_along(df1), 
                   function(n) cbind(FID = data$V1[fid1[n]],
                                     read.table("myvertices.txt", 
                                                skip = fid1[n], 
                                                nrows = df1[n] -1, 
                                                sep = ",")))
data2 <- do.call(rbind, listdata)  # Combine all the read tables into a single data frame.
```